# how to take a grey scale numpy image and tint it red

Tags: python, image, numpy, scikit-image

I have a 2D grey scale image, loaded using imread.0

I want to colourise it.

whats the best way to use numpy/skimage/python to achieve this?

Comment: Use a sample image and show us the expected results?

Answer (score 2):

It will depend a bit on the exact format of your input. But the basic procedure should be as simple as:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from skimage import data, io
>>> 
# an example grey scale image
>>> grey = data.coins()
# a helper for convenient channel (RGB) picking
>>> RGB = np.array((*"RGB",))
# the actual coloring can be written as an outer product
>>> red = np.multiply.outer(grey, RGB=='R')
# save for posterity
>>> io.imsave('red.png', red)
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the syntax `np.array((*"RGB",))` - what is it called please and how does it work? I presume it creates a `numpy` array from something, somehow?

Comment: @MarkSetchell see for example [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448). The star unpacks the sequence "RGB" into "R", "G", "B". without the surrounding `(...,)` this would be parsed as three positional arguments to the `array` factory. Since we want a single tuple argument instead we put the parentheses; the trailing comma is disambiguation from non-tuple parentheses (same as with singleton tuples).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain. I am going to have to experiment quite a lot to get my head around that!

Answer (score 1):

if this is a single channel image you could convert it to a "redscale" image by doing something like this:

```
zero_channel = np.zeros_like(greyscale_array)
redscale = np.stack([greyscale_array, zero_channel, zero_channel], axis=2)
```

without fully understanding the shape of your array it's difficult to answer though

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import color
from skimage import img_as_float
from PIL import Image

jpgfile = Image.open("pp.jpg")

grayscale_image = img_as_float(jpgfile)
image = color.gray2rgb(grayscale_image)

red_multiplier = [1, 0, 0]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(8, 4),
                               sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax1.imshow(red_multiplier * image)

plt.show()
```